# Xhr is not logging the response if the status is 400

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple login route in express:

```js
//login
router.post('/login',async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
        console.log(user);
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                message: "username not found"
            });
        }

        const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password);
        if (!validated) {
            console.log('password is wrong')
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                message: "password not found"
            })
        }
        const {password,...others} = user._doc;
        res.status(200).json(others,{
            success: true,
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
})
```

I am using react for my frontend and axios to make requests:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_START'});
        try{
            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login',{
                username: userRef.current.value, //add the body
                password: passwordRef.current.value
            })
            if (res.data.success) {
                dispatch({type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",payload: res.data})//if everything is fine save it into the localstorage.
            }
            console.log(res,"something went wrong")
        }
        catch(err) {
            dispatch({type: "LOGIN_FAILURE"})
        }   
    }
```

Now the problem is whenever i sent a status code of 400 it doesn't log the response which i want to see if i want to let the user know what's going on.

It just logs:

**xhr.js:184 POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)**

I want to see the content the json i am sending back.
I didn't find any similar answers regarding this.

What am i missing?

Comment: Response which you want to see on status 400, you must log in catch block `catch(err) {console.log(err.response); dispatch({type: "LOGIN_FAILURE"}) } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios `400 Bad request` , you could `console.log(err.response)` in your catch block to get a more human-readable object.

`axios` errors come in three types: `message`, `request` and `response`.

```
catch(err) {
     console.log(err.response);
     dispatch({type: "LOGIN_FAILURE"}) 
}
```